# Attention Network Task using lme4 - optimal random effects structure?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, attention

I'm analysing reaction time data obtained using the attention network task (ANT). All participants were presented with three types of stimuli per trial - first, a warning tone (2 levels), then a cue (3 levels) and finally a target ('congruency', 2 levels) - repeatedly throughout the task. DV = rt to targets.
My hypotheses predict a main effect of each stimuli-type, and of course, their interactions.

Here's my current model using the lme4 package:

```
rt1 <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + tone*cue*congruency + (1 | subject), data, REML=FALSE,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun = 30000000)))
```

I've included a random intercept for subjects, but should I also include slopes per subject for each stimuli type? It may be prudent to capture the possibility that the effect of cue type (for example) is not the same for all participants, but I've never read this approach in the literature. I tried the following model but it failed to converge:

```
rt1 <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + tone*cue*congruency + (1 + tone | subject) + (1 + cue | subject), (1 + congruency | subject), data, REML=FALSE,control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun = 30000000)))
```

So, is my original model sufficient?
Thanks in advance for any advice.